# how to cache images with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, image, caching

I am working with an angularjs web app. I have a sidebar with images. In my localhost these images only load once because they are cached. When I push the web app to the web the images are not cached and everytime I switch to another state the images reload. Is there a way to cache the images in angularjs without adding extra headers to the server.

Comment: This might interest you: https://github.com/jBenes/angular-imgcache.js/tree/master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load the images [from a CDN](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/); if the expires headers were setup properly on the CDN, using a CDN allows your images to cache and meets your questions's requirement to *not* setup your expires headers. This should dramatically increase the speed at which your images load anyway.

If you still aren't getting results, even after you've setup a CDN to serve static content, I would make sure the filenames being served doesn't have some kind of cache-busting url that forces a new image to download each time (the source would look something like "`../path/to/image.png?23someRand0mString`".  And most browser's dev tools turn off caching when the dev tools are open (or at least they have a setting) so verify they *aren't* being cached; your images should be cached by default in most managed server configurations.